# Seems impossible to properly size Power Apps form in list sidebar

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-form, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I created a custom form for a Sharepoint Online list in Power Apps.  After configuring the app it seems impossible to properly change the size of the form as it appears in the sidebar.

From the start, without changing any size settings the form appears in the sidebar with half of the space empty. I assume this is not expected behavior.

[image]

If I try to configure a custom size for the app (Settings -> Display), for example increasing the default height from 790 px to 1024, the form simply gets squeezed to fit the previous boundaries.

[image]

Additionally, none of the seemingly relevant options appear in the settings, such as *Scale to fit* and *Lock aspect ratio*. They seem to be available in some instructions online.

[image: No options for aspect ratio, scale to fit etc.]

Steps that have been tried:

- Clearing browser cache
- Trying another browser
- Changing settings to landscape mode (no effect on the width of the sidebar)

Answer (score 0):

You can get full height by increasing height in Power App designer. Open Settings - Display - experiment by finding out at which number all content fits in one screen (yes, it will be zoomed out and hard to see - that is the point). This will leave you with only one scrollbar in SharePoint sidepanel. :)

Comment: This does not fix the problem. By configuring the size to Custom and increasing the height, such as from 790 to 890, will only squeeze the form to fit the previous boundaries. See the image in the original question.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Had the same problem - reloading form and publishing again fixed the issue. Some kind of glitch.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the size of the list form via File > Settings > Screen size + orientation.

Switch Size from “Custom” to “Small” or “Large” and the list form should be in the auto resize mode.

Reference:

[Customize a SharePoint list or library form by using Power Apps (Further customize your form).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form#further-customize-your-form)

Here’s another post with detailed information on custom list form for your reference:

[Increase the width of the power apps forms and add header.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Increase-the-width-of-the-power-apps-forms-and-add-header/td-p/95302)

Best,

Renjie Sun

Comment: By default the size is set as "Large" so the first screenshot in the original post shows the outcome.

Both of the posts that you link to reference options that are not available in the options menu, such as Scale to fit and Lock aspect ratio.

Comment: It seems like if I create a new canvas app in Power apps, all the relevant settings appear. On the other hand if the power app is created from within Sharepoint (List settings -> Form settings -> Customize in PowerApps) only a subset of the settings appear. 

This is a rather annoying feature. Is there a way to create a blank canvas app directly at make.powerapps.com and then use the canvas app as a Sharepoint form?